TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of null when using react-native-contacts
Problem Statement:
I am trying to use the react-native-contacts library to fetch contacts in my React Native app. However, even after granting the required permission, I encounter the following error:
Permission: granted
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of null]


Environment:

React Native version: 0.76.4
Library: react-native-contacts (^8.0.4)
Platform: Android
OS: Windows-11
Device: Emulator and Physical Device


Code:
Here is my code:
ContactsScreen.tsx:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

const ContactsScreen: React.FC = () => {
    const contacts = () => {
        PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS, {
            title: 'Contacts',
            message: 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
            buttonPositive: 'Please accept bare mortal',
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('Permission: ', res);
                Contacts.getAll()
                    .then((contacts) => {
                        console.log(contacts);
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Permission error: ', error);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        contacts();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Contacts</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 16,
        backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
    },
});

export default ContactsScreen;

AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />


What I Have Tried:

Verified that permissions are granted using the logs.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project using npx react-native run-android.
Checked the react-native-contacts documentation to confirm API usage.
Confirmed that the permissions are listed in the AndroidManifest.xml.
I have even tried cd android && gradlew clean && cd ..


Expected Behavior:
The app should fetch and display contacts after permissions are granted.

Actual Behavior:
Even though the app logs that the permission is granted, it throws the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of null


Additional Notes:

I followed the installation steps for react-native-contacts as per the documentation.
The issue persists on both emulators and physical devices.


Question:
Why is the Contacts module returning null for the getAll method? Is there a step I am missing during the setup or configuration? I have to just get access to all contacts, then I will find way to render them in stylish format. Just need to get contacts first.
Any answer is appreciated, I am spending almost 2-3 days no result.
Thanks all.

In first request access for Permissions to get access for contacts, Once the permission is granted then we get the contacts and for that we have to do two states for that one is for permission and the second is for Contact.
        const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);
        const [contactList, setContactList] = useState<any[]>([]);
    
        const getContactsPermission = async () => {
            try {
                const permission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS, {
                    title: 'Contacts',
                    message: 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
                    buttonPositive: 'Please accept',
                });
    
                if (permission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                    setHasPermission(true);
                    console.log('Permission granted');
                    fetchContacts();
                } else {
                    setHasPermission(false);
                    console.log('Permission denied');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Permission error:', error);
            }
        };
    
        const fetchContacts = () => {
            Contacts.getAll()
                .then((contacts) => {
                    console.log('Fetched Contacts:', contacts);
                    setContactList(contacts);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Failed to fetch contacts:', error);
                });
        };
    
        useEffect(() => {
            getContactsPermission();
        }, []);
    
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Contacts Screen</Text>
                {hasPermission ? (
                    <View>
                       {contactList.length > 0 ? console.log(contactList):<Text>Empty List</Text>}
                    </View>
                )}
            </View>
        );
    };


Bro it is not working. I am sking for different thing, you are giving different answer. As you can see in above I am sharing my terminal. It is telling me that permission is granted and then giving this problem. Thanks )
